# how to update multiple Mongodb documents in-place using python

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I am a newbie in Mongodb. I have a collection and want to update one or more rows of it in-place. In fact, I have a new row and want to add/merge it with old rows. Each document has this format:

```
   {"CST_NUM": ....,
    "MAX_TRX_TIME": ....,
    "CNT_TRX_MONTH": ...,
    "processing_codes": {"00": {"t": ...}}
    }
```

For example, the new row is like this and I have to merge it with old one:

```
 new_row = {"CST_NUM": "710122663192_6280231481588597",
  "MAX_TRX_TIME": "2017/08/22 15:11:52.678910",
    "CNT_TRX_MONTH": 1.5,
    "processing_codes": {"00": {"t": 51}}
}
```

Now I want to update one or more rows. I use this command in python:

```
  mytable.update_many(
    {"CST_NUM": "710122663192_6280231481588597"},
{
"$set": {"MAX_TRX_TIME": "new_row.MAX_TRX_TIME","CNT_TRX_MONTH": "CNT_TRX_MONTH"+"new_row.CNT_TRX_MONTH", "processing_codes.00.t": "processing_codes.00.t"+"new_row.processing_codes.00.t"}

}
)
```

Would you please guide me how I can do in-place update in Mongodb?

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I update records in place using this code in Mongodb.
Every record in Mongodb is like this:

```
  {
"CUSTOMER_ID": "71",
"COUNT": 15,
"PROCESS": {"00": {"true": 3, "false": 0}, "01": {"true": 2, "false": 0}},
"UNIQUE_TERM": []
```

}

Now, I receive a record like this in Update Function:

```
   {
"CUSTOMER_ID": "71",
"COUNT": 15,
"PROCESS": {"00": {"true": 2, "false": 1}, "01": {"true": 1, "false": 0},"34": {"true": 3, "false": 1}},
"UNIQUE_TERM": ['123']
```

}

So, I have to search in Mongodb; if the record is there, I must update that. Otherwise, I have to insert the record. I use this code:

Making a dictionary variable to use in Update Command:

```
 process_command = {'PROCESS.{}.{}'.format(k, t): records['PROCESS'][k][t] for k, v in records['PROCESS'].items() for t in v.keys()}
```

Update command:

```
 mytable.update_one(
       {"CUSTOMER_ID": dic["CUSTOMER_ID"]},
         {
       "$inc": {
            "COUNT_TOTAL": dic["COUNT_TOTAL"],
                },
        "$inc": process_command,
        "$addToSet": {"UNIQUE_TERM": {"$each": dic["UNIQUE_TERM"]}}
    }, upsert=True
 )
```